# Create an 'active' class for partial url?

Tags: routes

I have a system of menus on a site that helps the user drill down to the page they are looking for.  If they click a link in the main nav, it might take the to /category.  On that page, a sidebar menu would direct them to /category/page.

Previously, I have used the active class to highlight a menu item while the user is on that page.  In this case, I want both menu items to be highlighted, since the page the user is on falls is a part of the main category.

To clarify, how can I keep a link active if it points to /category and the page the user is viewing is /category/page?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module for that - [Menu Trail By Path](https://drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path)

Menu Trail By Path sets the active-trail on menu items according to the current url.

For example if you are at `yoursite.com/blog/category1/article1`

Menu Items with these paths will get the active-trail class on them and expand accordingly.

```
blog
blog/category1
blog/category1/article1
```

This is particularly useful if you want a lot of nodes to appear as children of certain `nodes / taxonomy term / views / referenced nodes / etc`, but do not want to add them all to the menu. eg. hundreds of blog articles.

Menu Trail By Path is best used in conjunction with [Pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto).